# Qt очистка содержимого GraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsview

Разрабатываю приложение, которое по загруженному текстовому файлу, где находится матрица смежности графа, вырисовывает сам граф. Всё работает, рисуется как задумано, но только когда ты загружаешь файл один раз. Нужно приложение перезапускать. При повторной загрузке файла (этого же или другого) на сцене начинает вырисовываться какая-то дикость. Вот как выглядит всё в первый раз:
[image: Вот как выглядит всё в первый раз:]
При повторной загрузке файла получаем следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Такое ощущение, что содержимое вьюхи растягивается до каких-то невообразимых размеров.

Код, который отвечает за это работу GraphicsView ниже:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    ui->setupUi(this);    
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
  scene->clear();
  bool isSymmetric = true;
  QString file_name = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Open a file", QDir::homePath());
  QFile file(file_name);
  if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly |QIODevice::Text))
    {
...
    }
   file.close();
   ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
   nodes[1] = scene->addEllipse(x[i], y[i], 30, 30, blackPen, whiteBrush);
}
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, может быть я как-то не так очищаю сцену? Или есть какие-то определенные дополнительные функции для удаления расположенных на ней объектов?

Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Код, который отвечает за это работу GraphicsView здесь отсутствует, покажите создание item-ов, может быть замените для начала свой граф на простой квадрат для отладки

Comment: @PavelGridin Здравствуйте! Извините, не хотел нагромождать, добавил фрагменты с созданием items.

Comment: ну сделайте простую фигуру для отладки вместо графа, обычно обратная проблема - сцена расширяется чтобы все нарисованное охватить и от clear она не уменьшается

Comment: может вы там что-то с QTransform лишнего наделали, но почему не видно скролбаров? или они на маке autohide?

Comment: @PavelGridin Изменил код выше. Попробовал с обычным кругом - при первом открытии файла работает нормально, при повторном опять всё растягивается. Скролбары есть, просто они скрываются.

Comment: нет setScene надо в конструктор, может в этом дело, после setupUi

Comment: Только что попробовал перенести в конструктор, всё то же

Comment: ну оставьте в функции только `scene->clear();  scene->addEllipse(x[i], y[i], 30, 30, blackPen, whiteBrush);`, если хотите положите весь проект куда-нибудь github,sourceforge,gdrive - посмотрю

Comment: Сейчас попробую. Вот проект на GitHub: https://github.com/lord-anonymoose/GraphView .  Спасибо!

Comment: Если в функции оставить только очистку и добавление эллипса, всё идет нормально. Может быть, проблема связана именно с работой в файле?

Comment: @PavelGridin Извините, я нашел ошибку, она необычайно проста - не обновлялся итератор, который использовался при построении графа. Из-за этого цикл длился бесконечно и, видимо, сцена бесконечно расширялась. Спасибо огромное за помощь!